# Embedded resource has project name as prefix

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I'm working with a project called "MyApp", and all embedded resources get published into the dll like "MyApp.Sdk.System" instead of just "Sdk.System" which I want.

How do I omit the project name from appearing in the resource path?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the 'Default namespace' option in a project's properties?  You can change things there that affect how the naming scheme works with embedded resources.

**Edit**
See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3089/Understanding-Embedded-Resources-in-Visual-Studio) link for naming conventions on embedded resources.